# NextJS build referencing test files

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, dockerfile, vitest

After adding tests to my NextJS project I am finding that my Docker build fails because I use `RUN npm ci --omit=dev` to inject dependencies into my Docker pod. The build tries to reference test files even though my folders `/tests` and `__mocks__` are siblings to the `/src` entry point of my project. These two folders are the only ones referencing test code. Using either vitest or jest and their respective config files (vitest|jest.config.ts) I find that my production build is looking to my test files to be included.

I have tried adding `"exclude": ["node_modules", "tests", "vitest.config.ts"]` to my `tsconfig.json` file to ignore them in my build but I get the error

> Type error: Cannot find type definition file for 'vitest/globals'

Trying to remove `"types": ["vitest/globals"],` from the tsconfig.json causes more errors to pop up like leaks in a ship. Trying to track down these errors, adding vi as an explicit import and such, causes further issues and even issues with VS Code so I know this is not the way.

I was expecting the build to not need test files and their dev dependencies as NextJS docs say to add them to dev dependencies even.

Is `npm ci --omit=dev` not needed now with NextJS's new SWC compiler? Is there some step I'm missing in this configuration of my tests and build?

Comment: I resolved this by removing `"types": ["vitest/globals"],` and added in explicit imports for vi everywhere. I still had to explicitly exclude my vitest.config.ts file from the tsconfig.ts :(